# Navigation bar with drop down not working

Tags: html, css

I'm doin' a navigation bar for a website. I created it etc. but when I go to one of the sub menu's it disappears..

here's my HTML:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Welcome</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Review</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Customer Reviews</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Leave a Review</a></li>
        </ul>   
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Discounts</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Refer us!</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Claim discount</a></li>
        </ul>   
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Send me an email!</a>
    </li>

</ul>
</nav>
```

and my CSS:

```
/* nav */

nav{
text-align:center;
}

nav a:visited{
    color:black;
}

nav a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:black;

}

#menu {
margin:0 auto;
display: inline-block;
list-style-type:none;
padding:0;
}

#menu li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    list-style-type: none;
    background:white;
    border:1px solid black;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-top:5px;
    border-radius:4px;
}

#menu li a {
font-family:helvetica;
display:block;
padding:10px 10px;
text-decoration:none;
}   

#menu li a:hover {
    color:orange;
}

#menu li ul {
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #ffffff;
        margin-top:6px;
        margin-right:1px;
        padding: 2px; 
    }

/*#menu, #menu ul {
    margin:0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}*/
#menu li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    list-style-type: none;
}

#menu > li:hover > ul {
    display: block;

}
#menu > li > ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
}
#menu li a {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

and a little JSFiddle for ya: http://jsfiddle.net/nv741s01/

If you hover your mouse over a menu option [that has a sub-menu] long enough and then do it, it works, but people won't be willing to wait three seconds every time they want to visit a sub menu, so how do I resolve it so that it works as soon as you go to it?

any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `margin` of an element doesn't capture hover events. Use padding instead. Make these changes:

```
#menu li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    list-style-type: none;
    background:white;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-top:5px;
    margin:0;
}

/* add this rule */
#menu li a {
    border:1px solid black;
    border-radius:4px;
}

#menu li ul {
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #ffffff;
        margin-top:0px;
        margin-right:1px;
        padding: 2px; 
    }
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nv741s01/2/

Comment: I think it's something to do with my browser, because as I can see it works in the fiddle but when I do tests in Firefox it doesn't work.. know any reason as to why this is? I'll accept your nonetheless because I know it's right, it's just my browser being funny

Comment: @TreyTaylor happened to me too on chrome. I think it's because the gap is so small, it only sometimes triggers an un-hover event.

Comment: I'm using Firefox, so it looks like a all-browser kinda thing, hopefully when published it won't do this hahaha

Answer (score 3):

It was because there was a little gap between the sub menu and the menu, here is the fixed JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/nv741s01/3/

And here is what I changed:

```
#menu li ul {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #ffffff;
    margin-top: 1px;
    margin-right:1px;
    padding: 2px; 
}
```

I changed the margin-top to 1px.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `margin` to position the submenu away from the main item. Since margin isn't part of the actual element it doesn't trigger any `hover` behaviours. Instead, use `padding` on the child `ul` element, since padding is actually considered part of the child's box. This will make the hover behaviours trigger consistently when moving the mouse from parent to child.

You also describe that there's a 3 second delay somewhere - that's impossible from this code, and I cannot reproduce it obviously.

Comment: Well on the JSfiddle it seemed if I kept my mouse there for roughly 3 seconds I could then go onto the child elements.

Answer (score 0):

Your dropdowns are disappearing because as you move your mouse cursor down, there's a gap between the parent menu item and the child menu item.

When the mouse leaves the parent `li` space, it no longer applies to the hover state, and so the CSS rule is ignored, leaving the child menu hidden.

If it helps, I tend to use a combination of margins and padding, to 'bump together' the parent and child menus, to help navigation.